# Re-writing this sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have written an SQL query that gets unread messages but I think I can improve the code (speed and readability). The first select is for COUNT function, the second is for grouping messages according to conversation_id, and the final nested select is for selecting last messages.

Please give me suggestions. Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as unreaded FROM ( 
  SELECT id 
  FROM (
    SELECT id, conversation_id
    FROM messages
    WHERE to_id = ?
    AND readed = 0
    and NOT hide_from = ?
    ORDER BY sended DESC
  ) AS temp_messages 
  GROUP BY conversation_id
) as temp_messages2
```

Comment: "unread", not "unreaded" and also "sent" instead of "sended". Those would improve readability at least ;)

Comment: Do you want only the total unread messages count?  Or `unread,id,conversation_id`? what is `id`? It'll be better if you  post ddl, sample and expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query as-is will not work - you need to define all columns that aren't wrapped in aggregates in the `GROUP BY`.

It's not clear, but if you want a count of unique conversations, use:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT m.conversation_id) AS unread
  FROM MESSAGES m
 WHERE m.to_id = ?
   AND m.readed = 0
   AND m.hide_from != ?
```

...otherwise, use:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS unread
  FROM MESSAGES m
 WHERE m.to_id = ?
   AND m.readed = 0
   AND m.hide_from != ?
```

- The subqueries are unnecessary
- The `ORDER BY` is a waste of resources because it is not used in the ultimate output nor is `TOP` being used
- The `GROUP BY` won't work because `MESSAGES.id` is not in the list of columns

Comment: I upvoted, but I'm thinking from the way he wrote his query that the `*` might need to be a `DISTINCT id`... it *seems* like that's what he's after, although it's a little hard to tell.

Comment: I actually think he wants distinct conversation_id, because of that mysterious group by in the subquery

Answer (score 0):

Does that even work? id isn't in an aggregate, so you can't select ID group by conversation.

That being said, you're looking for conversations that have unread messages?

```
select count(distinct conversation_id) from message
 WHERE to_id = ? 
   AND readed = 0 
   and NOT hide_from = ?
```

should get you what you need

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as unreaded FROM ( 
  SELECT id, conversation_id
  FROM messages
  WHERE to_id = ?
  AND readed = 0
  and NOT hide_from = ?
  GROUP BY conversation_id
) as temp_messages2
```

You don't need the `order by` clause, and you can move the `group by` clause into the inner subquery.

Comment: Won't work - needs to be `GROUP BY id, conversation_id` because there's no aggregate on the `id` column.  It would work if the query were ran on MySQL, though I doubt the results would be correct.